# Выдернуть формулу из What-If-Analysis (Data table)

Tags: excel

Столкнулся с задачей - разобраться в экселевском проекте и переписать его на R.

Вижу таблицу, в каждой ячейке которой в графе формула отображается

```
{=TABLE(F2,C2)}
```

Я примерно понял, как это создается

```
(What-If-Analysis (Data table))
```

Но как мне понять, откуда скопирована изначальная формула (которая использует `F2`, `C2`) и по какой формуле рассчитываются значения в таблице?

Пример:
Сделаем Data Table, как показано  [тут](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/data-tables.html), лист будет выглядеть [так](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/images/data-tables/one-variable-data-table-result.png):

[image: SO32606771 question example]

В моем случае (не примере), я не знаю, как был сделан лист, а вижу только, как он выглядит сейчас. Вместо формулы я вижу что-то вроде `{=TABLE(,C4)}`. 
(В приведенном примере найти формулу не сложно, она находится в клетке (D10), которая уже в свою очередь использует C4 (через клетки C7 и С8).

Как найти эту формулу, не зная, как создавался Data Table?

Comment: "Но как мне понять, откуда скопирована изначальная формула" -  а нам как понять, о чем речь? Пример нужен.

Comment: @Ogurtsov спасибо за комментарий, подредактировал описание

Comment: Думаю на первом этапе  если проект не сильно сложный можно посмотреть как происходит влияние C4 на B12 ( я бы нарисовал зависимые стрелочки в эксель  `b12`--формулы-- влияющие ячейки( несколько раз пока не придешь к значению с4)), то есть придется смотреть как итоговый результ получают из значения переменной , которую меняют.